# Authentication Subversion write-through proxy

Tags: svn, authentication, proxy, mirror

Since version 1.5 Subversion supports to have a local caching-proxy for the main Master-repository.

I got the slave synced and the master replaying the commits to the slave. 
Everything works fine so far, but now I am wondering how to do the authentication (working with [this](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/10/yesterday-at-th.html) guide).

When both, the master and the slave, have authentication set, the slave asks for username/password on reads, but both ask on writes.

What is the way to also get authentication transparent to the user of the slave (meaning requiring only 1 authentication independent if it is read or write)?

I am testing with:

- Apache/2.2.3, Subversion 1.4.2 on the slave (Debian)
- Apache/2.2.8, Subversion 1.5.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the problem was solved by configuring the mod_proxy correctly. 
Ones mod_proxy is aware that is also has to proxy the authentication credentials, it works fine and the user has to enter username/password only once.

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly you solved that? Facing a similar problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering the password must surely be up to the svn client you're using, why would it ask you again if you told it to remember it?

Also you might want to read up on apache, specifically the Require directive, which controls HTTP authentication: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require

Usually `Require valid-user` is used

Comment: How to do authentication in general is not the question, but how to avoid that slave and master require authentication (making the user enter credentials twice).